# The meaning of the word "transpire"

Tags: meaning

I have always found the word "transpire" interesting. I am curious about if I can use "sth transpires to be sth" instead of "sth happens to be sth"? Or how does that sound to you? Academic? Too formal? Quirky?

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transpire)'s definition is as follows:

> intransitive verb
>   1 :  to take place :  go on, occur
>   2 a :  to become known or apparent :  develop
>   b :  to be revealed :  come to light
>   3 :  to give off vaporous material; specifically :  to give off or exude watery vapor especially from the surfaces of leaves
>   4 :  to pass in the form of a vapor from a living body transitive verb :  to pass off or give passage to (a fluid) through pores or interstices; especially :  to excrete (a fluid, such as water) in the form of a vapor through a living membrane (such as the skin)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although the 'turn/s out' sense is idiomatic (It transpires that there were no WMDs there), I wouldn't use 'X transpires to be [a] Y' myself. There are plenty of hits on the internet for "transpires to be" though.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use that?

Comment: My impression is that 'It transpires that' is bordering on the highfalutin, but 'Joe transpires to be an earl' has crossed the border. Data from  [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+transpires+that%2Ctranspires+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20transpires%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctranspires%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0) might suggest that many are in agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/transpire), transpire comes from  the Middle French transpirer, which in turn comes from the Medieval Latin trānspīrāre, equivalent to Latin trāns- trans- + spīrāre to breathe.

Metaphorically, a whisper of information is "breathed" through the walls of a sealed room, or (more likely) betrayed by a participant.

In modern usage, *transpire* is almost the same as *occur* or *it turned out that*.  However, you can use it in its original sense to give a slightly dated feel to your text, e.g.

- The King met privately with his generals.
- It **transpired** that the attack on Vienna would take place at dawn.

To say that "something transpired to be something" goes against the sense of "breathing through the wall".  It would be hard to make it sound natural.